# How to find Order of submitted input in $_Post when the html form includes file input

Tags: php, file-upload, http-post

I have a standard HTML form with jquery creating more elements.

Text with name="text[]"

Text with name="text[]"

Image with name ="images[]"

Text with name="text[]"

User can add more image or Text field with Jquery and with unique incremental ids, .

I am using $_Post to submit the form.

I want to process this data as follows :

Concatenate in Order ->

$_Post[text[1]].$_Post[text[2]]. [Process file $_File[image1] and return url.$_Post[text[3]].....

I am able to do this when form has text only, but file input is creating great problem to sequence the submitted data.

I do not know the order before hand because users are expected to use Jquery to "Add Image" or "Add text" at will.

How do I process this in PHP.

Thanks in Advance, please please reply using a loop example.

Notes: It is Single image upload.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Put the binary image data into a string together with your text input? Please explain in more detail what you want to do and provide more complete code, thats just nonsense

Answer (score 0):

You can check the $_POST will have the array of images and text,
example:

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])){
  foreach($_POST['text'] as $text){
   // You can get each element here in $text
  }
}
```

same for images field

```
if(isset($_FILES['images'])){
  foreach($_FILES['images'] as $images){
    // You can get each element here in $images
  }
}
```

Comment: isset($_POST['images']) doesn't work and doesn't show anything. Images are processed by $_FILES[] separately. But thank you for your answer

Comment: I know that if it is files, in ur question u simply mentioned name ="images[]" ?

Comment: Updated, check now :)

Answer (score 0):

For using images[] this type you are using array to post data using post method

so simple use foreach loop to retrive that data using $_POST 
if not understand structure of it then use

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

TO SHOW STURCUTRE

Comment: var_dump($_POST) shows empty string for attached file, it does show the order of the submitted form but I am not sure how to loop through it. looping through ($_POST) doesn't show images while $_Files doesnt show text, how do I use var_dump information ?

Comment: use 
echo "<pre>";
print($_REQUEST);
print($_FILES);
IF YOU GETTING values in this so you can get all your values